# MySQL: How to select range in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm developing an online examination system and I want to get a data from the database if the score of the user is in the range set by the admin.

Range is dynamic and set by the admin.

Example:

**TABLE FIELDS VALUES:**

```
outcome_id | outcome_range
     1     | 2,5
     2     | 6,10
     3     | 11,15
```

**USER:**

If the user got 3 points it will get the data row *outcome id 1* from the table because the score is in the range of 2-5.

Comment: Are those ranges continuous? (Given the context it wouldn't make much sense otherwise.)

Comment: I Would Suggest splitting outcome range into 2 fields  Min_Outcome_Range And Max_outcome_range and then check if User_Got Between Min and Max

Comment: @yesitsme i'll try that thanks

Comment: And this is a theoretical background, why @yesitsme is right: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @yesitsme So, i will use sql BETWEEN operator?

Comment: yes if you wish, or you can use less <= And Greater >=

Comment: Is my answer not pretty? [inpage-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255519/mysql-how-to-select-range-in-mysql/36255718#36255718)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the range

**Table**

```
outcome_id | min_outcome | max_outcome
     1     | 2           | 5
     2     | 6           | 10
     3     | 11          | 15
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE min_outcome <= 3 AND max_outcome >= 3
```

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_name` (
  `outcome_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `min_outcome` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `max_outcome` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`outcome_id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `table_name` (`outcome_id`, `min_outcome`, `max_outcome`) VALUES
(1, 2, 5),
(2, 6, 10),
(3, 11, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second value (the max-points) *might* be superfluous if
a) the ranges are continuous and
b) you will select exactly 1 (or 0) outcome id

```
CREATE TABLE outcomes (
  outcome_id int,
  outcome_min int,
  unique index(outcome_min)
)

INSERT INTO outcomes (outcome_id,outcome_min) VALUES
  (1,2),
  (2,6),
  (3,11)

SELECT outcome_id FROM outcomes WHERE outcome_min>=3 ORDER BY outcome_min ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You not need to change your table structure.

just use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` mysql function to find the values as min and max value.

```
SELECT `outcome_id`, `outcome_range` FROM `test` HAVING SUBSTRING_INDEX(`outcome_range`, ',', 1) <= 3 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(`outcome_range`, ',', -1) >= 3
```

This Pretty thing also done by using the WHERE clause. The same result come out.

```
SELECT `outcome_id`, `outcome_range` FROM `test` WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(`outcome_range`, ',', 1) <= 3 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(`outcome_range`, ',', -1) >= 3
```

Here i use 3 as static value. you can use the dynamic one. This is a user input.

> Output:
>
> ```
> outcome_id    outcome_range   
>  1                2,5
> ```